# How to let laravel know that 2 (or many) many-to-many relationships are different when foreign keys are same

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Firstly I'm not well English, sorry about that.

In my case I have relationships many-many from `a` table to `b` table through `a_b` table. A row on `a` can `belongToMany` a row on `b` and differentiate them with `type` column on `a_b`.

```php
class A extends Model
{
   public function bs
   {
       return $this->belongToMany(B::class)
                   ->withPivot(['type']);
   }
}

class B extends Model
{
   public function as
   {
       return $this->belongToMany(A::class)
                   ->withPivot(['type']);
   }
}
```

The issue occur when i run `sync` method on that relationship, laravel can not differentiate  if I relate 2 relationships has the same foreign keys but diff `type`.

```php
A::find(1)->bs()->sync([
   B::find(1)->id => ['type'=>1],
   B::find(1)->id => ['type'=>2],
])

A::find(1)->bs()->where('id', 1)->count() // is 1 but I want it is 2
```

Comment: I suggest making a separate `AB` model with one to many relationships between `a` and `b`. There's little support in Laravel for many-to-many with duplicated rows.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you, I thought about it before too, but hope there is a better solution

Comment: The problem is even with the syntax `[ id => [ pivot ]]` the key of the array must be unique so you can only specify the given id once. You can't call sync separately either because it will dettach before syncing and you can't use `syncWithoutDetaching` because that only attaches the ids that are not there already so the limitation looks like is built into the system.

Comment: @apokryfos Wow that is a big problem I didn't realize

Answer (score 1):

Try by using `bs` instead of `bs()`, otherwise, you will be using method chaining, and `where()` condition will be applied as query builder to related models instead of relationships collection.

```
A::find(1)->bs->where('id', 1)->count();
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean. but the main problem is that the `sync` method only imports one and adds this to the `a_b` table.